# Can not compile in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Hello I am getting this error that I can not seem to go away. I am using IntelliJ CE current release, I have done a few fresh installs of the IDE. Nonetheless, I always get this error.

Here is the project I was working on:

[image]

My sanity check didn't work.. .
[image]

Also even more interesting… 
only on the first run, when I open up any Java Project, I get this error:

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.VerifyError) Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 90
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/jetbrains/kotlin/jps/build/KotlinBuilder.createCompileEnvironment(Ljava/util/Map;Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/incremental/components/LookupTracker;Lorg/jetbrains/jps/incremental/CompileContext;Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/jps/build/KotlinBuilder$MessageCollectorAdapter;)Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/compilerRunner/JpsCompilerEnvironment; @171: goto
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: bb03 fe59 b703 ff3a 0619 063a 0719 0713
    0x0000010: 02d7 2cb6 0403 5719 0713 0405 bb04 0759
    0x0000020: 2b3a 083a 093a 0a3a 0b3a 0c19 083a 0dbb
    0x0000030: 0409 5919 08b9 040a 0100 b804 10b7 0411
    0x0000040: c002 893a 0e19 0db9 028c 0100 c000 b03a
    0x0000050: 0f19 0fb9 00b9 0100 3a10 1910 b900 be01
    0x0000060: 0099 004d 1910 b900 c201 003a 1119 0e19
    0x0000070: 11c0 028e 3a12 3a13 1912 b902 9101 00c0
    0x0000080: 00c4 b804 173a 1419 1319 1419 11c0 028e
    0x0000090: 3a15 3a16 3a17 1915 b902 9401 003a 1819
    0x00000a0: 1719 1619 18b9 041b 0300 57a7 ffaf 190e
    0x00000b0: 0000 3a13 190c 190b 190a 1909 1913 b704
    0x00000c0: 1eb6 0403 5719 0713 0420 bb04 2259 2c2b
    0x00000d0: 2db7 0425 b604 0357 1907 b604 283a 052a
    0x00000e0: b704 2c3a 0619 06c6 0010 1906 b904 3101
    0x00000f0: 00b6 013c 9a00 1319 04b2 0216 1304 3301
    0x0000100: 0701 b801 fa01 b0bb 0262 5919 0619 05b2
    0x0000110: 002e b604 3719 04c0 01c7 bb04 3959 b704
    0x0000120: 3ab7 043d b0                           
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@90,{Object[#2],Object[#649],Object[#727],Object[#98],Object[#428],Top,Object[#1022],Object[#1022],Object[#649],Uninitialized[#28],Uninitialized[#28],Object[#1005],Object[#1022],Object[#649],Object[#649],Object[#176],Object[#187]},{})
    same_frame_extended(@174)
    full_frame(@247,{Object[#2],Object[#649],Object[#727],Object[#98],Object[#428],Object[#1102],Object[#1070],Object[#1022],Object[#649],Object[#1031],Object[#1031],Object[#1005],Object[#1022],Object[#649],Object[#649],Object[#176],Object[#187],Top,Top,Object[#649]},{})
    same_frame(@263)
java.lang.VerifyError: Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 90
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/jetbrains/kotlin/jps/build/KotlinBuilder.createCompileEnvironment(Ljava/util/Map;Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/incremental/components/LookupTracker;Lorg/jetbrains/jps/incremental/CompileContext;Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/jps/build/KotlinBuilder$MessageCollectorAdapter;)Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/compilerRunner/JpsCompilerEnvironment; @171: goto
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: bb03 fe59 b703 ff3a 0619 063a 0719 0713
    0x0000010: 02d7 2cb6 0403 5719 0713 0405 bb04 0759
    0x0000020: 2b3a 083a 093a 0a3a 0b3a 0c19 083a 0dbb
    0x0000030: 0409 5919 08b9 040a 0100 b804 10b7 0411
    0x0000040: c002 893a 0e19 0db9 028c 0100 c000 b03a
    0x0000050: 0f19 0fb9 00b9 0100 3a10 1910 b900 be01
    0x0000060: 0099 004d 1910 b900 c201 003a 1119 0e19
    0x0000070: 11c0 028e 3a12 3a13 1912 b902 9101 00c0
    0x0000080: 00c4 b804 173a 1419 1319 1419 11c0 028e
    0x0000090: 3a15 3a16 3a17 1915 b902 9401 003a 1819
    0x00000a0: 1719 1619 18b9 041b 0300 57a7 ffaf 190e
    0x00000b0: 0000 3a13 190c 190b 190a 1909 1913 b704
    0x00000c0: 1eb6 0403 5719 0713 0420 bb04 2259 2c2b
    0x00000d0: 2db7 0425 b604 0357 1907 b604 283a 052a
    0x00000e0: b704 2c3a 0619 06c6 0010 1906 b904 3101
    0x00000f0: 00b6 013c 9a00 1319 04b2 0216 1304 3301
    0x0000100: 0701 b801 fa01 b0bb 0262 5919 0619 05b2
    0x0000110: 002e b604 3719 04c0 01c7 bb04 3959 b704
    0x0000120: 3ab7 043d b0                           
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@90,{Object[#2],Object[#649],Object[#727],Object[#98],Object[#428],Top,Object[#1022],Object[#1022],Object[#649],Uninitialized[#28],Uninitialized[#28],Object[#1005],Object[#1022],Object[#649],Object[#649],Object[#176],Object[#187]},{})
    same_frame_extended(@174)
    full_frame(@247,{Object[#2],Object[#649],Object[#727],Object[#98],Object[#428],Object[#1102],Object[#1070],Object[#1022],Object[#649],Object[#1031],Object[#1031],Object[#1005],Object[#1022],Object[#649],Object[#649],Object[#176],Object[#187],Top,Top,Object[#649]},{})
    same_frame(@263)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.jps.build.KotlinBuilderService.createModuleLevelBuilders(KotlinBuilderService.java:30)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.BuilderRegistry.<init>(BuilderRegistry.java:54)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.BuilderRegistry.<init>(BuilderRegistry.java:33)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.BuilderRegistry$Holder.<clinit>(BuilderRegistry.java:36)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.BuilderRegistry.getInstance(BuilderRegistry.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:133)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:295)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:236)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$$Lambda$4/386536307.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$$Lambda$2/670035812.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

also here is the first error in text:

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError) Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.BuilderRegistry$Holder
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.BuilderRegistry$Holder
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.BuilderRegistry.getInstance(BuilderRegistry.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:133)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:295)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:236)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$$Lambda$14/473199672.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$$Lambda$2/670035812.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

P.S. HALP I don’t wanna use eclipse!!!

Comment: Are you on Max OS X ?

Comment: Yes I am using macOS High Sierra 10.13.1 Beta

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-156147

Comment: @Leif what JDK version is used for compilation? Does it happen with the latest Java release from Oracle?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have used 7 and 8 both get the same error.

Comment: @Leif please confirm that 1.8.0_152 release produces this problem.

Comment: @Leif does it help if you disable Kotlin plug-in? See also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19660.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Disabling the Kotlin plug-in seemed to fix it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [an open issue logged](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19660), but the problem is not easily reproducible. It may help to update the project SDK to the most recent version (like 1.8.0_152).

**Kotlin** plug-in [can be disabled](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html) as a workaround if you are not using it.

Comment: This just happened to me with IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 (Build #IU-213.5744.223, built on November 27, 2021) on openjdk 17.0.1 2021-10-19 with maven 3.8.

Seems to be related to Quarkus extension we developed and `annotationProcessorPaths`.
However I was the only one with this issue in the whole team and we all use the same versions of whole stack. 
However I'm the only one using Ubuntu (`5.11.0-41-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 10 10:20:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`).

@CrazyCoder thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's a known JDK issue: [JDK-8046233](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046233)

Please, update your Java installation.

Comment: This does not solve it, also CrazyCoder already posted updating as a solution... This seems like a duplicate answer or low quality...